# .Net Core + Angular - hosting an application using IIS and Self host together

Tags: angular, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to host an app in 2 environments together. One is iis and the other is a self host.
With iis I host the app in the following path:

> http://localhost/WebApplication14

While in the self host I host the app in the following path:

> https://localhost:5001

The problem is that in order to work with IIS, I had to change the Build command at package.json:

> "build": "ng build --baseHref=/WebApplication14/"

From now on only IIS works and Self Host does not

I tried to set the app to listen to a similar path in a self host mode but regularly get an error from Kestrel

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://*:5000", "http://localhost/WebApplication14")
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

How Should i build the UseUrls lines in order to do the magic ?

Of course, the paths I mentioned are for example only.
In fact, the same application should work under a real IIS server and a stand alone version on an offline computer.

I'll be glad to receive your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the exact answer you're looking for, but two separate builds?

#### package.json

```
.
.
.

"build": "ng build,
"buildProd": "ng build --base-href /WebApplication14/ --deploy-url /WebApplication14/"
.
.
.
```

`npm run build` or `npm run buildProd`

Comment: It was also my first instinct. However, I would like to create a single publish profile using the visual studio interface. Additionally When you do Publish by visual studio, it automatically runs the build command

Answer (score 0):

May following program.cs would help you

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace LeaveManagementSystem
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
             .UseKestrel()
             .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .UseIISIntegration()
             .UseStartup<Startup>()
             .Build();

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code generates the following error:
Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use. ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
what am I missing?

Comment: rather than adding two urls,just check with single one .UseUrls("http://*:5000");